# How can I fill columns from a special row

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a Listview generated in wpf

see here:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstVCOM" Height="450" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="25" Header="Slot" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Slot}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Messung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MessungNr}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Minimal" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Min}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Maximal" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Max}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Aktuelle Messung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MessungAkt}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Durchschnitt" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Durschnitt}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I want fill for example step by step , that means I want first fill the Slot column then the Messung column then..... all in row 1 then go to the next row and do the same.

How can I do that ?

lstVCOM.item.add ?

thx

Comment: You want to manually add them? Or do you mean add them to a `Collection` that will then represented with the `ListView`?

Comment: I want maually add them

Comment: Each column manually, or each row manually? Why not make an object to represent a row, then you'll be adding a row at a time instead of a column

Comment: Each row manually : first I want write a value for "Slot" , then a value for "Messung" then .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `object` that represents a row, I've named it `VCOM`, then you can create a `List<T>` for representing the collection of the `VCOM`s.

```
public class VCOM {
    public int Slot { get; set; }
    public string MessungNr { get; set; }
    public decimal Min { get; set; }
    public decimal Max { get; set; }
    public string MessungAkt { get; set; }
    public decimal Durschnitt { get; set; }
}

private List<VCOM> _ListVCOM = new List<VCOM>();
public List<VCOM> ListVCOM {
    get {
    return _ListVCOM;
    }
    set {
    _ListVCOM = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("ListVCOM");
    }
}
```

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that your DataGrid will update when you add a new `VCOM` object to the `List<VCOM>`.

```
ListVCOM.Add(new VCOM() {
    Slot = 1,
    MessungNr = "Messung",
    Min = 0.0M,
    Max = 1.0M,
    MessungAkt = "Aktuelle Messung",
    Durschnitt = 0.5M,
});
```

To set the individual properties manually, you can retrieve the object and set other properties based on knowing the `Slot` property (assuming it will be unique).

```
int currentSlotNum = 1;
ListVCOM.Where(a => a.Slot.Equals(currentSlotNum)).First().Min = 1.0M;
```

Then when you want to add a new `VCOM` object, just call the above `Add Method` and it will update with the new row.

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstVCOM" Height="450" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListVCOM, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="25" Header="Slot" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Slot}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Messung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MessungNr}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Minimal" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Min}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Maximal" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Max}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Aktuelle Messung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MessungAkt}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Durchschnitt" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Durschnitt}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Here is the `DataGrid`, with appropriate `ItemsSource` binding.

Comment: i think this is not what he wants. He wants a small delay between setting the properties Slot, MessungNr, etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. @user2261524 How are you retrieving the values to be set? Can we see the code for that in your question please? You can always retrieve the object based on the `Slot` property and set them that way. Not sure about a pause, do you mean to use [Thread.Sleep Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332371(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: The values are getting from a microcontroller through a COM. I get the data every byte and collect them before I able to print it on my listview

Comment: @user2261524 You can always create a `VCOM` object, save all the properties to it as the data comes in, then add it to the `List<T>` after the object is completed.